# Condition for incompressible flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have given a set of differential equation (linear),
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= ax+by \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= cx+dy
\end{align}
where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are constants.
I'm trying to find out the condition so that area  elements remain same

$$dx(t)dy(t)=\text{constant}$$
That is a incompressibility condition of fluid element.

It seems to be Liouville's theorem that lead to conclusion :
$$\frac{\partial\dot{x}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial \dot{y}}{\partial y}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow a=-d$$
But I used this [sketch](https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1166546), It seems it didn't work. Is this condition right?

---

$\dot{x}$ stands for time derivative of variable $x$.

Comment: What is $\dot{x}$ ? What is $x'$ ? What is $d$ in $\dot{y} = cx+dy$ ? What is $d$ in $dxdy=dx'dy'$ ? Down vote because ambiguous notations.

Comment: @JJacquelin Please find the edit, and help me.